"Can only iterate over an array or an instance of java.lang.Iterable" error when I create a fabric mod minecraft 1.20.6?
I've begun fabric modding, and I want for my mod to load a resource pack when the mod is loaded.
Then I found in the fabric api a code snippet which I imported into my mod here:
package com.name.exampleMod;

import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.function.Predicate;
import java.lang.Iterable;
import java.io.InputStream;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import net.fabricmc.api.ModInitializer;
import net.fabricmc.fabric.api.resource.ResourceManagerHelper;
import net.fabricmc.fabric.api.resource.SimpleSynchronousResourceReloadListener;
import net.minecraft.resource.ResourceManager;
import net.minecraft.resource.ResourceType;
import net.minecraft.util.Identifier;

public class Concatenation implements ModInitializer {
    // This logger is used to write text to the console and the log file.
    // It is considered best practice to use your mod id as the logger's name.
    // That way, it's clear which mod wrote info, warnings, and errors.
    public static final String MOD_ID = "exampleMod";
    public static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MOD_ID);
    
    @Override
    public void onInitialize() {
        // This code runs as soon as Minecraft is in a mod-load-ready state.
        // However, some things (like resources) may still be uninitialized.
        // Proceed with mild caution.

        LOGGER.info("HOI!!! fabric World !!!");
        
                
                
        ResourceManagerHelper.get(ResourceType.SERVER_DATA).registerReloadListener(new SimpleSynchronousResourceReloadListener() {
            @Override
            public Identifier getFabricId() {
                return new Identifier("tutorial", "my_resources");
            }
 
            @Override
            public void reload(ResourceManager manager) {
                // Clear Caches Here

                for(Identifier id : manager.findResources("my_resource_folder", path -> path.endsWith(".json"))) {
                    try(InputStream stream = manager.getResource(id).getInputStream()) {
                        // Consume the stream however you want, medium, rare, or well done.
                    } catch(Exception e) {
                        LOGGER.error("Error occurred while loading resource json" + id.toString(), e);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
}

    public static String getModId() {
        return MOD_ID;
    }

    public static Logger getLogger() {
        return LOGGER;
    }
            
            
}

I don't know why I get the error Can only iterate over an array or an instance of java.lang.Iterable, considering I took the code from the documentation.
Here the link of the doc's code : https://fabricmc.net/wiki/tutorial:custom_resources
When I got the error I tried to see where is the problem. And in my research I saw that the problem can come from this function .findRessource(). The same function come from the minecraft api and this needs for argument a Predicate<Identifier> and the documentation tell the function needs for argument a Predicate. But, I don't know if this is it.

It looks like this part of your code: manager.findResources("my_resource_folder", path -> path.endsWith(".json")) does not return an Iterable - despite what is written in the documentation you linked to in your question, i.e. that it returns a collection of paths.

yeah, i see but i don't know if it come from a code whose only functional for another version of fabric and minecraft or just an outdated code. But i don't think it's an outdated code because, the doc's code got an update at 2024/06/29.

This seems a little out of left field at least from my modding knowledge. However the first comment posted on the question is right. If you take a look inside of the actual resource manager class it returns a collection. There is most likely a method that the ResourceManager class has which will allow you to get an iterable (one object that can be iterated over) from the collection.
A big part of modding for Minecraft is understanding the backend of what you're trying to add. Which includes looking inside of the class which you're trying to use. Looking for methods that might be useful to you is common practice in general modding.
Alternatively you can just ask the creator of the resource pack to use the resources in your mod or if you made it just put them in the mod resources/assets/textures/mod_id/sub-folder.
I'm not as proficient with Fabric as I am with Forge and NeoForge but I hope this answer helps!

I will try, i hope it work but if it don't work i thank you anyway for trying to help me.
